# This css not working with mozilla

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use `:placeholder` css pseudo selector.
How do I do this in Firefox?

```css
input::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #f00;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
input:focus:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #1abc9c;
  font-size: 11px;
  transform: translateY(-20px);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="test" />
```

Comment: A nice site to check: http://caniuse.com

Comment: http://materializecss.com/forms.html

I want this kind of form input in mozilla using pure css

Comment: what is the problem here?

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What is you Firefox version?

Comment: seems working to me, your using the firefox moz now you just need to define for other browsers and you should be fine.

Comment: You're mixing the deprecated `:-moz-placeholder` with the current one `::-moz-placeholder`.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't really make that clear in your question, but I suppose what you mean is not working is the change on ":focus". However, you have just forgotten the second colon in front of the pseudo selector, `:focus::-moz-placeholder`. If you add that, it works as supposed:

```css
input::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #f00;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
input:focus::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #1abc9c;
  font-size: 11px;
  transform: translateY(-20px);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="test" />
```